# Component not rerendering on route changing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React Hooks and my state (moduleName) is not getting updated even though the prop(which i get from route)changes? I need to use moduleName to useEffect Dependencies to make Api Call. 
I am also using **withRouter** at my component but it doesnt seem to rerender my component when route changes. My App.js looks like this

```
       <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Login} />
            <Route component={Routes} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
```

and at the component i need to re render on route changei have this

```
const ListView = (props) =>{  
const [moduleName, setModuleName] =useState(props.match.params.moduleName);

useEffect(() => { 
//api call here
}, [moduleName]);
}

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
null
)(withRouter(ListView));**
```

Comment: Instead of `moduleName` provide `props.match.params.moduleName` as dependency to `useEffect`.

Comment: yes that works, but i use moduleName on many places and dont want to make it look hard coded and problem is that the component rerenders but state moduleName dont get updated with new value

Comment: For that you need to do `setModuleName(props.match.params.moduleName)` in `useEffect`

Comment: done that too but doesnt work properly. for example i change route once, nothing happens, but when i change route for the second time the moduleName gets updated with the previous route param value

Comment: You need to call `setModuleName` at appropriate place, may be after success from your API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen prop changes inside the useEffect Hook, and you don't need to hold state for a prop, so you can delete useState hook

```js
const ListView = (props) =>{  

  useEffect(() => { 
    let moduleName = props.match.params.moduleName
    if(moduleName) {
       console.log(props.match.params.moduleName) 
      // do something when moduleName changes
      // api call
      axios.get('someurl/'+moduleName)
    }
  }, [props.match.params.moduleName]);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,null)(ListView));
```